# How to add float or decimal field using declarative schema in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have to create a table using declarative schema in Magento 2.3.5. Please advise me how to create decimal/float field using xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="tp_directory_city" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="City Directory Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="11" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="region_id" nullable="false" unsigned="true" padding="11" comment="Region ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="city_code" nullable="false" length="25" comment="City Code"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="City Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="decimal" name="shipping_price" nullable="false" length="255" comment="City Name"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Comment: you need to change your decimal to <column name="shipping_price" nullable="true" precision="12" scale="4" xsi:type="decimal"/>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to update your `db_schema.xml` file content with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="tp_directory_city" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="City Directory Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="11" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="region_id" nullable="false" unsigned="true" padding="11" comment="Region ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="city_code" nullable="false" length="25" comment="City Code"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="City Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="decimal" name="shipping_price" nullable="false" scale="2" precision="10" comment="Shipping Price"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it will helps!

Comment: Perfect! Let me try it, let you know

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: It works, Thanks Kishan

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.dckap.com/blog/declarative-schema-magento-2/ you need to use type="real" to define a decimal type